# When reading from a file I get special characters, that are not in my text file

Tags: c, file, io, filereader, fread

For starters, I don't know if it has to do with my OS by I am on OSx. When running my program and printing out what I read from the text file I get the following:

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z\353`\232\377
```

I am reading from a new text document I created using text wrangler, I even turned on invisibles to make sure there wasn't anything at the end of the file. The code I am using to read from the text file is here:

```
// Parses text from file, then passes parsed text to writeAndEncode for writing          and encryption. 
int encode(char *fileRead, char *fileWrite) {

    // Get the file
    FILE *fileToRead = fopen(fileRead, "r+"); // Open file for reading
    char *textWithinFile;

    // Check if the file can be read
    if (fileRead != NULL) {
        // File can be read.

        // Get length of file
        fseek(fileToRead, 0L, SEEK_END);
        size_t size = (size_t)ftell(fileToRead);
        rewind(fileToRead);
        // Make sure no error in finding size of file.
        if (size != -1) {
            long charSize = sizeof(char);
            textWithinFile = malloc(sizeof(char) + size);
            // Add text from fileToRead to char array
            fread(textWithinFile, charSize, size, fileToRead);
            // Add null at end to make file string
            textWithinFile[size] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", &textWithinFile[0]);
            fclose(fileToRead); // Debugging to find out what is being read

            writeAndEncode(size, textWithinFile, fileWrite);
            free(textWithinFile);
        } else {
            //File Can't be read
            printf("***ERROR_FILE_TO_READ_SIZE_CAN_NOT_BE_FOUND***\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("***ERROR_FILE_TO_READ_CAN_NOT_BE_READ***\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Would I have this same problem if I was on Windows?

Anyhow thank you for any help!

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned type, it never can be `-1`, use `long` to get the size returned by `ftell`

Comment: Perhaps you ought to check the return values from `fread()` (among others...) and do the appropriate thing when the values returned are not what you assume they should be...

Comment: `if (fileRead != NULL)` should be `if (fileToRead != NULL)`. `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition. You don't check the value returned by `fread`. `printf("%s\n", &textWithinFile[0]);` is ok, but `printf("%s\n", textWithinFile);` is simpler, and `puts(textWithinFile)` is even simpler. What is `writeAndEncode`?

Comment: To store `size` characters as a regular C style zero terminated string, you need an array of size `size+1`. The extra position is to store the `0` in, as it will not be in your file length. What is `writeAndEcode`? Since you use `size` in its call, more likely the error is in there.

Comment: @KeithThompson WriteAndEncode is a method within the program that takes the text grabbed (including the garbage at the end) encodes it and writes it to another file. It shouldn't have any effect on the reading aspect of the program.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` will always be one, it's specified by the standard.

Comment: And note, just because `sizeof (char)` is one you get away with `textWithinFile = malloc(sizeof(char) + size);`, where for any other type (and here) it more properly should be `textWithinFile = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);`

Comment: Why multiplication @DavidC.Rankin ? And can I just replace sizeof(char) with 1?

Comment: Because you are generally reserving space for the number of whatever `type` you are reading. Consider the case where you are reading `int` from the file. Each `int` is `4-bytes`, so to read `x` number of `int` you would need `sizeof(int) * x`. (granted that in this case where pre-reading the length of the file, that is taken care of for you)

Comment: @Alter Mann Even though a `size_t` variable can never have the value `-1`, `size != -1` can be false.  IWO `size == -1` can be true.  Agree `size` should be `long size`.

Comment: @David C. Rankin Using `textWithinFile = malloc(x * sizeof *textWithinFile);` deals well with the `sizeof(char)` or `sizeof(int)` issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed up your code a little and added some debugging statements. It'll save the contents of the input file into an `malloc`'ed buffer of `size=(charSize*filesize+1)`, with the `+1` bit to hold the null terminating character. It works on my machine with reasonably sized binary files

You can uncomment the `printf(buffer_copy)` statement to get what you were doing before. Otherwise, it'll now loop through each byte in the buffer and output as its hexadecimal equivalent. If you're still getting that 'junk' then it's just part of your input file and not a bug.

```
//get the file
FILE *infp=fopen(infile,"r");
if(infp!=NULL){
    //get length of file
    fseek(infp,0L,SEEK_END);
    size_t filesize=(size_t)ftell(infp);
    printf("file length = %d\n",(int)filesize); //debug statement
    rewind(infp);
    if(filesize>0){ 
        char * buffer;
        buffer=(char*)malloc((sizeof(char)*filesize)+1); // +1 for null char at the end
        size_t chars_read=fread(buffer,sizeof(char),filesize,infp);
        printf("chars read = %d\n",(int)chars_read); // debug statement (chars_read should equal filesize)
        buffer[filesize]='\0'; // properly terminate the char array
        fclose(infp);
        //output what you read (method 1, print string)
        //char *buffer_copy=buffer; 
        //printf("the file=\"%s\"",buffer_copy); //uncomment these two statement to do what you did before */
        //output what you read (method 2, byte-by-byte)
        if(chars_read>0){
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<chars_read;i++){
                char the_char = *buffer;
                printf("char%d=%02x\n",i,the_char); //output each byte as hexadecimal equivalent
                buffer++;
            }
        } else { printf "problem with fread"; }
    } else { printf("problem with filesize"); }
else { printf("problem opening the file"); }
```

The `while` loop would stop reading at the first null terminating char. The `for` loop will now read every single byte inside the file (in case you're trying to peek inside something that isn't necessarily `.txt`, like `.jpg`)

---

Have you tried checking the file from the command line to make sure it only has the characters you expect?

For example, by running the command `od -c` to view each byte as its ASCII equivalent (or octal, if non-printable).

Comment: How would I do that within terminal? od -c [filename] ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to un coment that trailing `'\0'` append

```
//textWithinFile[size] = '\0';
```

Comment: Ah yes I was doing that to see if maybe the C program didn't like that I was appending that NULL. Nonetheless, it still prints out those numbers at the end. Are those hex for invisibles?

Comment: @AlterMann: No, they're not the same -- and `sizeof(char) + size` is correct, since it allocates an extra byte for the terminating null character. It's better written as `malloc(size + 1)`. Uncommenting the assignment of `'\0'` is likely the answer.

Comment: @MiguelJ.: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant; the null character is `'\0'`, not `NULL`. The numbers at the end are garbage. With no terminating `'\0'`, `printf` reads past the end of your array.

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes, sorry, too much coffee :P

Comment: @AlterMann: No such thing. 8-)}

Comment: @KeithThompson Would I have to add the null to the end of the text file before reading it some how? I add the null after it reads for writing the data to another text file later on, evidently after I read it it's too late to add that null character. Even in my text file if I manually add \0 in it it still gives me the garbage at the end.

Comment: @MiguelJ.: No, you don't need, and in general should not have, null characters in text files. A null characters are used to mark the end of a string in memory. If you want to read the contents of a file into a string, you'll need to allocate space for an extra byte (which you've done) and set that byte to `'\0'` (which you've commented out). Or, probably better, you can just read the contents of the file into an array of the appropriate size and then *don't treat that array as a string*.

Comment: @KeithThompson Why am I getting the junk at the end of the read though? I add the null to the end, which just append it to the end of the junk.

Comment: @MiguelJ.: In the original version of your question, the code that added the `'\0'` was commented out. You've now edited the code in the question. Have you verified that you're still getting the extra characters when that line is present?

Comment: Yes. I added the NULL after the file is read..... so it reads it, stores the text, THEN I add NULL then I print it out. That NULL after the fact shouldn't have an effect as to how it reads the file right?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Xcode was acting up for me. I tried compiling this with terminal and it worked out fine. Thank you for you help everyone.